# Keep different sized images proportional when resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to keep 10 different sized images stay proportional when resizing, and stay on each row. I can't change the way this is laid out as I am working from a .jsp for a client and it is pulling the info from a post that I can't edit. Which is why I am not using rows/cols.

The HTML looks like this.

```
                <div>
                    <p>
                    <!-- Top Row -->
                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/1.jpg" height="231" width="216"></a>

                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/2.jpg" height="231" width="191"></a>

                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/3.jpg" height="231" width="215"></a>
                    <!-- End Top Row -->
                    <!-- Second Row -->
                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/4.jpg" height="167" width="311"></a>

                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/5.jpg" height="167" width="311"></a>
                    <!-- End Second Row -->
                    <!-- Third Row -->
                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/6.jpg" height="173" width="216"></a>

                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/7.jpg" height="173" width="191"></a>

                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/8.jpg" height="173" width="215"></a>
                    <!-- End Third Row -->
                    <!-- Fourth Row -->
                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/9.jpg" height="173" width="311"></a>

                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/0.jpg" height="173" width="311"></a>
                    <!-- End Fourth Row -->
                    <!-- Banner -->    
                        <img src="/images/uploaded/1516_thumbs/banner.jpg" height="252" width="622">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

For the CSS I have tried switching from "body_content" and the div with this code

```
 div#body_content div {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
 }
```

and

```
 div#body_content div p a img {
    float: left;
    min-width: 33.333%;
    width:100%
 }
```

And about a million variations on this and can't figure out how to keep everything in their row. 
I am also using Bootstrap for this.

Comment: I don't understand. Why aren't you using rows and cols classes?

Comment: Its because I am working on a .jsp site, and can't change the way that portion is laid out. 
I meant to add this to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap you can do

```
 <div>
            <div class="row">
            <!-- Top Row -->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/1.jpg" height="231" width="216"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/2.jpg" height="231" width="191"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/3.jpg" height="231" width="215"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            <!-- End Top Row -->

            <!-- Second Row -->
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/4.jpg" height="167" width="311"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/5.jpg" height="167" width="311"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            <!-- End Second Row -->

            <!-- Third Row -->
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/6.jpg" height="173" width="216"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/7.jpg" height="173" width="191"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/8.jpg" height="173" width="215"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            <!-- End Third Row -->

            <!-- Fourth Row -->
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/9.jpg" height="173" width="311"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="/images/uploaded/0.jpg" height="173" width="311"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            <!-- End Fourth Row -->
            <!-- Banner -->  
                <div class="row">  
                <img src="/images/uploaded/1516_thumbs/banner.jpg" height="252" width="622">
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I can't do this because I can't change the HTML to do this. Someone else already said this, and I edited the OP already to state that I can't change it.
Thank you anyway!